# weird behaviour of warn and print with code blocks in perl

Tags: perl

program : testblocks.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hi";

BEGIN {
        warn "BEGIN";
}
END {
        warn "END";
}
INIT {
        warn "INIT";
}
CHECK {
        warn "CHECK";
}
UNITCHECK {
        warn "UNITCHECK";
}

print "Hello";
```

Output:

```
BEGIN at testblocks.pl line 8. 
CHECK at testblocks.pl line 17. 
INIT at testblocks.pl line 14. 
UNITCHECK at testblocks.pl line 20. 
END at testblocks.pl line 11. 
HiHello
```

Now if I use, `\n` in print statements like below

```
print "Hi\n";
...
print "Hello\n";
```

Output is:

```
BEGIN at testblocks.pl line 8.
CHECK at testblocks.pl line 17.
INIT at testblocks.pl line 14.
Hi 
UNITCHECK at testblocks.pl line 20.
Hello 
END at testblocks.pl line 11.
```

I am unable to understand the issue here. Any inputs or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a print buffer issue. When you include a newline in your print, buffers get flushed right away. In your first case, without a newline, they get flushed when they are full, or when your program exits.

As [dgw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1137055/dgw) comments, since `warn` goes to STDERR and print to STDOUT, they are also not in the same buffer.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that `print` goes to `STDOUT` and `warn` to `STDERR`.